python "remove" method - why did the method change other variables?
I am not understanding why Py is doing this.

"xx" variable was already assigned as "thislist" prior to any changes to "thislist"
I am expecting xx to remain as ["apple", "banana", "cherry"].

thislist = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
xx=thislist
thislist.remove("banana")
print(f"thislist={thislist}")
print(f"xx={xx}")


xx is not a copy of the original list, just another name for it.

thanks. so how do i get xx to maintan as ['apple','banana','cherry']?
